# explicit specialization "..." is not a specialization of a function template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to specialize a function template but I'm getting an error (title) and I don't know how to solve it. I'd guess it is due to the mixed types I use in the template specialization. The idea is just to use int as double in the specialization. Many thanks.

```
template <typename T>
T test(T x) { return x*x; }

template <>
double test<int>(int x) { return test<double>(x); }
```

Comment: `double test(int)` mismatches `T test(T)`, hence the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> explicit specialization “…” is not a specialization of a function template

True.
Because you defined `test()`

```
template <typename T>
T test(T x) { return x*x; }
```

receiving a `T` type and returning the *same* `T` type.

When you define

```
template <>
double test<int>(int x) { return test<double>(x); }
```

you're defining a specialization that receive a `int` value and return a different type (`double`).

So there is no match with `T test(T)`.

You can solve the problem through overloading

```
double test(int x) { return test<double>(x); }
```

Answer (score 6):

As you correctly said, you are using for the return type `T = double` but for the parameter `T = int`, which isn't valid.

What you can do instead is provide a non-templated overload:

```
template<typename T>
T test(T x) { return x*x; }

// regular overload, gets chosen when you call test(10)
double test(int x) { return test<double>(x); }
```

Of course, someone can always call `test<int>(/*...*/);`. If that is not acceptable, just delete the specialization:

```
template<>
int test(int) = delete;
```